# How to lossless optimize images with plugins for grunt-contrib-imagemin?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, imagemin, grunt-contrib-imagemin

I am trying to **lossless** optimize JPEG / PNG images with `imagemin`, but I have a problem when using extensions, they "deoptimize", meaning the result image is bigger than the original. How can I prevent this?

This is my **Gruntfile.js**

```
...
grunt.initConfig({
    imagemin: {
        jpeg: {
            options: {
                //by default it uses imageminJpegtran
                progressive: true,//default false, progressive JPEG is better compression https://superuser.com/questions/463477/progressive-jpeg-quality-compare-to-normal-jpeg
                arithmetic: false,//true breaks image

                //don't know how to use it loseless without making the images even bigger
                // use: [
                //  imageminMozjpeg({
                //      quality: 95, //Compression quality, in range 0 (worst) to 100 (perfect).
                //      dcScanOpt: 2,//2 Optimize between one scan for all components and one scan for 1st component plus one scan for remaining components
                //      arithmetic: false// false, or it breaks the image
                //  }),
                // ],
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '/www',
                src: ['**/*.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}'],
                dest: '/www',
                filter: 'isFile'
            }]
        }
    }
});
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You have the answer in the title of your question – `"grunt-contrib-imagemin"`. If you google it you will find **[this page on GitHub](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin)** for Grunt.js as official Grunt GitHub site. *On this page it is all described very detailed.*

**For example:**

For imagemin OptiPNG plugin:

> `optimizationLevel` **(It is for PNG (for OptiPNG plugin) and NOT FOR JPG!)**
>   Type: `number`
>   Default: `3`
>   Select optimization level between `0` and `7`.
>
> The optimization level `0` enables a set of optimization operations that require minimal effort. There will be no changes to image attributes like bit depth or color type, and no recompression of existing `IDAT` datastreams. The optimization level `1` enables a single `IDAT` compression trial. The trial chosen is what `OptiPNG` thinks it’s probably the most effective. The optimization levels `2` and higher enable multiple `IDAT` compression trials; the higher the level, the more trials.
>
> Level and trials:
>
> 1. `1` trial
> 2. `8` trials
> 3. `16` trials
> 4. `24` trials
> 5. `48` trials
> 6. `120` trials
> 7. `240` trials

**Do not try** to use `optimizationLevel` for JPG! For JPG and PNG you will find different optimisation options. **All the types of this optimization <s>levels</s> options are full described on the plugins sites (see the plugins listing below).**

On **[this site](https://github.com/imagemin)** you have a lot of plugins for different image types optimisation. In your case they are JPG and PNG (you have there also for WebP, Gif and SVG):

**Plugins for JPG optimization:**

- **[jpegtran plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran)**
- **[mozjpeg plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-mozjpeg)**
- **[jpegoptim plugin for Imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegoptim)**

**Plugins for PNG optimization:**

- **[pngquant plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-pngquant)**
- **[pngout plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-pngout)**
- **[optipng plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-optipng)**
- **[pngcrush plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-pngcrush)**
- **[AdvPNG plugin for imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-advpng)**

All PNG plugins have different optimization <s>levels</s> options. For example for AdvPNG plugin you have an `optimizationLevel` as option and you can select an optimization level between `0` and `4`:

> `0` Don't compress
>   `1` Compress fast (zlib)
>   `2` Compress normal (7z)
>   `3` Compress extra (7z)
>   `4` Compress extreme (zopfli)

**JPG optimization**

And for JPG optimization I would like to recommend the `mozjpeg` and `jpegoptim` plugins because they have a lot of options for configuration – see the links for this plugins above.

**Example of usage from plugins**

```js
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const jpegoptim = require('imagemin-jpegoptim');
//const mozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
const pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

(async () => {
    const files = await imagemin(['images/*.{jpg,png}'], 'build/images', {
        plugins: [
            //jpegoptim plugin for JPG
            jpegoptim({
                progressive: true, //Lossless conversion to progressive.
                max: 80 //try to set with and without this option
                //see other options on plugin site (link above) and take / add which you need
            }),
            /* As comment because on plugin page is nothing about lossless conversion
            // mozjpeg plugin for JPG
            mozjpeg({
                quality: 80
                //see other options on plugin site (link above) and take / add which you need
            }),*/
            //pngquant plugin for PNG
            pngquant({
                quality: [0.7, 0.8]
                //see other options on plugin site (link above) and take / add which you need
            })
        ]
    });

    console.log(files);
    //=> [{data: <Buffer 89 50 4e …>, path: 'build/images/foo.jpg'}, …]
})();
```

**[Source](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin)**

For PNG lossless conversion try also to use the AdvPNG plugin without any options. `optimizationLevel` option for AdvPNG plugin is by default setted to `3` (from `0` to `4`).

**Advanced reading**

It is very important to read the article:

- **[A guide to PNG optimization](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html)**

Comment: That is not an answer of how to do loseless with mozjpeg! Not even png

Comment: @max4ever, I have added the example of how to use `mozjpeg` and `jpegoptim` plugins for JPEG few days ago. And for PNG I had it already in my answer. Unfortunately, I do not get any feedback from you. Please write me answer.

Comment: so the jpegoptim { max: 80 } is lossless in your opinion? because i see the official documentation says "Set maximum image quality factor. (0-100). ", anyways I should have named this question how to use mozjpeg, but thanks

Comment: By `max: 80` I wrote comment "try to set with and without this option". With this option it is not lossless. Even with `max: 99` is not because it is JPEG. But I wrote also `progressive: true, //Lossless conversion to progressive.` And I don't understand why you can not see this! I wrote very good answer, I have done a lot of research after a solution for you and I do not understand why I get only the criticism as feedback! It is really unfair! And for "how to use mozjpeg?" you can also find the answer in my answer – all is described on plugin page. For each plugin documentation I have links.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `optimizationLevel` option. This value ranges from 0 to 7, with 3 as the default.

For instances:

```
imagemin: {
   dist: {
      options: {
        optimizationLevel: 5
      },
      files: [{
         expand: true,
         cwd: 'src/images',
         src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
         dest: 'dist/'
      }]
   }
}
```

In this example the images optimized are those with the extension png, jpg, or gif, and located in the “src/images” folder and all its subfolders. The result of the optimization will be stored in the “dist” folder.

[Adapted from here.](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-grunt-tasks-improve-performance-website/)

Comment: That's not what the question is about, plus this only applies to png, i asked about jpeg please

Comment: This applies to png, jpeg or gif.